# What is the defined behavior of std::string::erase() with a pos of string::npos?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring, outofrangeexception

What does the C++11 standard specify for the behavior of the `string& erase (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos);` member function when the `pos` argument is passed as `string::npos`?  I would think it should erase nothing, but perhaps it throws an `out_of_range` exception instead?  What is the defined behavior for the standard?

Answer (score 3):

It throws `std::out_of_range`, as specifically stated in the standard:

> **21.4.6.5 basic_string::erase** [**string::erase**]
>
> **basic_string& erase(size_type pos = 0, size_type n = npos);**
>
> *Requires*: `pos <= size()`
>
> *Throws*: `out_of_range` if `pos > size()`.
>
> *Effects*: Determines the effective length `xlen` of the string to be removed as the
>   smaller of `n` and `size() - pos`. The function then replaces the string
>   controlled by `*this` with a string of length `size() - xlen` whose first
>   `pos` elements are a copy of the initial elements of the original string
>   controlled by `*this`, and whose remaining elements are a copy of the
>   elements of the original string controlled by `*this` beginning at
>   position `pos + xlen`.
>
> *Returns*: `*this`.

Answer (score 1):

It throws `std::out_of_range`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase.

The general principle is that values of`pos` between 0 and `size()` (i.e. one past the end) are fine, but anything beyond that indicates caller error.